# What is the best way for large data movement task

Tags: python, amazon-s3, multiprocessing

I am working on a solution that downloads the files from a third party service and need to upload those files into aws s3.
I need to download 1year of data and upload to s3.

- for each day no of files are 10K to 15K
- Download each file and upload to s3
- add a metadata record in db for future reference.

I've implemented a python script to download the files for each day and upload to s3. I used multiprocessing but i am not sure how to run it for whole year dates.

What would be the best and time efficient way to process this.

My code looks like this

```
def download_files(date):
    file_list =  get_file_list(date)
    for file_path in file_list:
        local = download_file(file_path)
        s3_key = upload_to_s3(local)
        insert_record_to_db(s3_key, file_path)
        os.remove(local)

def get_dates(month):
    days = calendar.monthrange(2023, month)[1]
    return [f"{month}-{day}-2023" for day in range(1,n+1)]

pool = mp.Pool()
dates = get_dates(1)
pool.map(download_files, dates)
```

Comment: Where you are keeping the downloaded file in the interim step before uploading into S3 ? You may explore the option of using AWS DataSync to upload your downloaded files into S3 bucket.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/what-is-datasync.html

Comment: why multiprocessing ?  also, the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)